# How can I build a json payload from a csv file that has string data separated by line using Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks, read.csv

In an overview, let's say I have a CSV file that has 5 entries of data (I will have a large number of entries in the CSV file) that I need to use dynamically while building the JSON payload using python (in Databricks).

**test.csv**

```
1a2b3c
2n3m6g
333b4c
2m345j
123abc
```

**payload.json**

```
{
 "records": {
    "id": "37c8323c",
    "names": [
      {
        "age": "1",
        "identity": "Dan",
        "powers": {
          "key": "plus",
          "value": "1a2b3c"
        }
      },
      {
        "age": "2",
        "identity": "Jones",
        "powers": {
          "key": "minus",
          "value": "2n3m6g"
        }
      },
      {
        "age": "3",
        "identity": "Kayle",
        "powers": {
          "key": "multiply",
          "value": "333b4c"
        }
      },
      {
        "age": "4",
        "identity": "Donnis",
        "powers": {
          "key": "divide",
          "value": "2m345j"
        }
      },
      {
        "age": "5",
        "identity": "Layla",
        "powers": {
          "key": "power",
          "value": "123abc"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above payload that I need to construct as a result of multiple ***names*** objects in the array and I also would like the ***value*** property to read dynamically from the CSV file.

I basically need to append the below JSON object to the existing names array considering the value for the power object from the CSV file.

```
      {
        "age": "1",
        "identity": "Dan",
        "powers": {
          "key": "plus",
          "value": "1a2b3c"
        }
      }
```

Since I'm a newbie in Python, any guides would be appreciated. Thanks to the StackOverflow team in advance.

Comment: good question.  However, you have 5 items in the list `test.csv` and only 2 places in the  `payload.json`...  so are you asking to add more places in the `json` ?

Comment: Yes the total would be 5 different objects inside the names array. In real, i will have to append around 20k objects under the names array. This was just an example. The final output i expect to be the same number of entries in the csv file and the same number of objects inside the array. Appreciate you helping out.

Comment: understood:  if there is a 1 to 1 relationship, then each `id` needs to come with the rest of the (example) data. So, please add this to the question.

Comment: Understood. Done editing it.

Comment: are you **writing to** or **reading from** the CSV file?

Comment: Reading from the csv file first then after construction the payload, need to write it to the blob as well. But the problem is constructing the payload after reading csv file from blob like i mentioned. Apologies if i wasn’t clear